# shell script issue for paired end files name matching

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I have list of files where for each file there are two set of files forward and reverse.

```
KIMS2021-01_R1.fastq.gz  KIMS2021-05_R2.fastq.gz  SRR1734377_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006898_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006903_1.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-01_R2.fastq.gz  KIMS2021-06_R1.fastq.gz  SRR1734377_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006899_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006903_2.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-02_R1.fastq.gz  KIMS2021-06_R2.fastq.gz  SRR6006895_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006899_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006904_1.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-02_R2.fastq.gz  SRR1734374_1.fastq.gz    SRR6006895_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006900_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006904_2.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-03_R1.fastq.gz  SRR1734374_2.fastq.gz    SRR6006896_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006900_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006905_1.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-03_R2.fastq.gz  SRR1734375_1.fastq.gz    SRR6006896_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006901_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006905_2.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-04_R1.fastq.gz  SRR1734375_2.fastq.gz    SRR6006897_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006901_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006906_1.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-04_R2.fastq.gz  SRR1734376_1.fastq.gz    SRR6006897_2.fastq.gz  SRR6006902_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006906_2.fastq.gz
KIMS2021-05_R1.fastq.gz  SRR1734376_2.fastq.gz    SRR6006898_1.fastq.gz  SRR6006902_2.fastq.gz
```

My objective is to pass these files for input which simple when all the files are having similar naming pattern followed here i have data coming from two different sources..

This is the command i do run

```
for i in $(ls *.fastq*.gz | sed 's/00[0-9]\.gz/.gz/' | rev | cut -c 17- | rev | uniq); do STAR --runMode alignReads --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate --runThreadN 30 --genomeDir /run/media/punit/data3/Santosh_star_index --readFilesIn  <(gunzip -c ${i}_R1_001.fastq.gz ${i}_R2_001.fastq.gz ) --outFileNamePrefix ${i%};done
```

The idea is I should get one file name for each of the set.

This command works for the files which starts with SRR ids, as i have tried

```
for i in $(ls *.fastq*.gz | sed 's/00[0-9]\.gz/.gz/' | rev | cut -c 12- | rev | uniq); do echo $i; done
```

The output of the above is as such

```
KIMS2021-01_
KIMS2021-02_
KIMS2021-03_
KIMS2021-04_
KIMS2021-05_
KIMS2021-06_
SRR1734374
SRR1734375
SRR1734376
SRR1734377
SRR6006895
SRR6006896
SRR6006897
SRR6006898
SRR6006899
SRR6006900
SRR6006901
SRR6006902
SRR6006903
SRR6006904
SRR6006905
```

Here i can see the SRR id become unique where as the KIIMS are not.
So any suggestion or help how do i make them similar pattern to run it once.

The naive way is to run them as two different sets rather one but i would like to learn how to do when there are different kind or different length of naming

**UPDATE**

This code does what i want that is uniform name

```
for i in $(echo *.fastq*.gz); do echo ${i%_*}; done | uniq
```

Now i want to use it with rest of my command

```
 do STAR --runMode alignReads --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate --runThreadN 30 --genomeDir /run/media/punit/data3/Santosh_star_index --readFilesIn  <(gunzip -c ${i}_R1_001.fastq.gz ${i}_R2_001.fastq.gz ) --outFileNamePrefix ${i%};done
```

Now my issue is with i have 2 `do` that wont work but How do i pipe the name to the command

Comment: You need remove last `_` and everything after it from file name. This can be achieved with `${i%_*}`.

Comment: dumb question how will i achieve that just rename all my files name ?

Comment: As an aside, that's a [useless use of `ls`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#ls)

Comment: for i in $(ls *.fastq*.gz | sed 's/00[0-9]\.gz/.gz/' | rev | cut -c 12- | rev | uniq); do echo ${i%_*}; done

Comment: @tripleee for biologist these simple stuffs are like grinding my head i try just enough to get it done

Comment: Using `printf` instead of `ls` is not more complex, it's less complex, and much less error-prone. In general, [never use `ls` in scripts.](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), precisely because of all the complications.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what exactly your question is here; if the duplicate does not answer your question, perhaps try to [edit] this into a clearer and more focused question. If you do that, feel free to ping me here like @tripleee to get this reopened.

Comment: for i in $(ls *.fastq*.gz | sed 's/00[0-9]\.gz/.gz/' | rev | cut -c 17- | rev | uniq); do STAR --runMode alignReads --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate --runThreadN 30 --genomeDir /run/media/punit/data3/Santosh_star_index --readFilesIn  <(gunzip -c ${i}_R1.fastq.gz ${i}_R2.fastq.gz ) --outFileNamePrefix ${i%};done
 this is what i have to run let me try first then will ping

Comment: @tripleee Question in close resolution is about adding characters not removing.

Comment: well i saw i can;t use do twice in that loop which i want to use

Comment: @YuriGinsburg The criteria for closing for duplicate is whether the _answers_ are substantially the same, not the questions. See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not/194495#194495

Comment: @YuriGinsburg i have added a comment to your answer ...

Comment: @tripleee it partially helped me i would be really glad if you can check my updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
for i in $(echo *.fastq*.gz); do echo ${i%_*}; done | uniq
```

**edit** Replaced `ls` with `echo`. @triplee is right, this is more reliable.

Comment: yeah i did that it worked i posted in my comment thank you for giving me a new trick to work with files

Comment: Glad that I could help.

Comment: for i in $(ls *.fastq*.gz); do echo ${i%_*}; done | uniq; do STAR --runMode alignReads --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate --runThreadN 30 --genomeDir /run/media/punit/data3/Santosh_star_index --readFilesIn  <(gunzip -c ${i}_R1.fastq.gz ${i}_R2.fastq.gz ) --outFileNamePrefix ${i%};done this is what i want to run but i cna;t use do twice which i saw now...how to fix? this

Comment: that part is sorted but the step where i want to pipe the file to the actual tool is im making a mistake

Comment: Also [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor)

Comment: `for i in $(echo *.fastq*.gz)` is wrong as well. The correct way is `for i in *.fastq*.gz`.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Is wrong?  Does it produce incorrect result for file name formats specified by OP?

Comment: It invokes a subshell unnecessarily and more importantly, it may produce wrong file list if a filename contains blank characters or glob characters.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin OP provided two strict formats for input file names. Neither of them contains spaces.

Comment: @PesKchan I think that problems with your pipeline are subject fo separate question. please post it and I will try to help.

Comment: Then why did you replace `ls` with `echo`? There is no visible  difference between `for i in $(echo *.fastq*.gz)` and `for i in $(ls *.fastq*.gz)`.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin For two reasons: 1. another comment suggested that.2. `ls` invokes an external command, `echo` does not.